# Internet Connection timing out If I don't stream video online

Tags: video, ping, timeout

I have a problem with my broadband connection because it's always timing out until I accidentally discovered that it will stabilize once I play online videos like youtube..

Please see image attached below.. I want to understand why this is happening..

**This is my connection looks like If I don't play any video from youtube**
[image: This is my connection looks like If I don't play any video from youtube]

**And surprise! This is what happen when I stream a video from youtube.. It will stabilize when there is moderate to heavy network usage**
[image: And surprise! This is what happen when I stream a video from youtube.. Its kinda fix or stabilize.]

Comment: What kind of broadband connection do you have? What hardware handles your end of the connection?

Comment: You may want to contact your service provider, I don't think you will be able to solve this on your end. Looks like bandwidth shaping problem to me, but that's just wild guess.

Comment: @david Schwartz Im using wimax and it has external antenna..   I only have here the modem and then wifi router..   I don't have any idea why streaming helps to improve my connection

Answer (score 1):

Even the second lot of ping results looks flaky & has high latency... I'm surprised the video plays without stalling. I'm guessing you're using satellite or 3G? If it was me, I'd invest in an external antenna if possible to increase the signal strength.

Comment: Hi Alex  Im okay with that since that is the best I can get during evening.. Morning is much beter around 100ms

Comment: Cool, 100ms is much better :)

Comment: This is wimax 4G and already using outdoor antenna.. Do you think increasing the antenna height would make difference?

Comment: Possibly... depends on where the nearest tower is. If it has clear line of sight to the tower, it should work better. Being higher usually means less trees, buildings, etc. to reduce the signal.

Comment: signal indicator shows full(5 bars) and sometimes 4 bars..  Anyway what do you think  the science behind why  playing a YouTube video is somehow a temporary fix ?? :)

Comment: @mboy It's probably your WiMAX/4G radio trying to minimize the amount of communication between you and the tower at the cost of quality of service. Have you ever tried using a VPN or checking your radio's settings?

Comment: @oldmud0 & Alex The problem was the router ...I monitored it by pinging the  modem local IP through the router , pinged another device in the network and pinged google.com and found out that even other devices in the WiFi network is timing out except the wired ones

Comment: I replaced the router earlier and I'm now getting <=100ms ping reply from Google.com :)

Comment: @mboy hmm, okay. You should post that as an answer.